# AWS Console is not listing my Elasticsearch domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

AWS console is not more listing my ElasticSearch domains, Although I still can query the domain and it returns the results. You can see below the Postman request.

[image: AWS Elasticsearch results]
But when I logged in to AWS Console, it shows no any Elasticsearch domain and shows only thier Get Started Page.

Comment: Are you in the correct region?

Comment: How could I miss this? Yes, you are right, I was in different region :( Thank you.